# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk failing on deployment from time to time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Usually I can deploy to the server with no issues (using Bitbucket pipelines) but occasionally the server crashes on deployment and this is what I get from the logs:

**eb-engine.log**

```
2021/10/22 13:39:59.079271 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Executing instruction: FlipApplication
2021/10/22 13:39:59.951321 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ An error occurred during execution of command https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/. Stop running the command. Error: remove current dir failed: unlinkat /var/app/current: directory not empty
2021/10/22 13:39:59.951338 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Executing cleanup logic
2021/10/22 13:39:59.951487 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":}
```

From my knowledge the way the deployment works is by basically copying the whole app to a new directory, then updates the symlink to the new directory, and then deletes the old directory. I think somewhere along this way something gets created inside this older directory and hence why the error happens.

I've tried posting on the AWS Developer Forums but no luck there.

Anyone has any ideas on what this could be?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: "something gets created" - its not clear. What exactly are you creating, coping to those folders?

Comment: @Marcin I'm not sure. The AWS deployment is all done automatically, is there anyway I can see the pipeline on AWS?